# how do i send this data to facebook? facebook api photo upload

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Okay so facebook want me to send an image stored locally on the server but i have the images stored in a BLOB in the database...

```
try {
     $file = 'http://blaze-craft.com/matt/get.php?id=' . $lastid;
    $post_data = array(
        "message" => "Uploaded using the Funnymemes app!",
         "source" => $file
     );
    $data['photo'] = $facebook->api("/me/photos", 'post', $post_data);

  }
  catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

  }
```

but its not uploading... I got this code from the facebook api doc's so im not sure whats going on?

any ideas?

Comment: That's one reason you shouldn't store images in your database. The sample code is trying to pull the image from a directory on your server.

Answer (score 3):

In order to photo upload to work you have to fix these:

1. Image files should be **stored in filesystem** (i.e. save BLOB back to
   the disk)
2. Use **`@` before image path** in `$post_data` array.

For this purpose i would do something like:

```
try
{
    $url    = 'http://blaze-craft.com/matt/get.php?id=' . $lastid;
    $saveas = '/images/image.jpg';
    $res = @file_put_contents($saveas, file_get_contents($url));

    if($res === false) throw new Exception('Cannot fetch image');

    $post_data = array(
        "message" => "Uploaded using the Funnymemes app!",
        "source"  => '@' . $saveas;
     );
    $data['photo'] = $facebook->api("/me/photos", 'post', $post_data);

  }
  catch (FacebookApiException $e) {  }
  catch (Exception $e) { }
```