# How to return Facebook Event ID after posting so I can add cover photo?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the following code (found on SO) to post Events on behalf of my Facebook page.

```
require_once 'fb-sdk/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => 'APPID',
    'secret' => 'SECRET'
));

$facebook->setAccessToken('TOKEN');

try {
    $retObj = $facebook->api('/PAGE_ID/events/create', 'POST', array(
        "name" => 'Test Event 1234',
        "description" => 'This is a test!!',
        "start_time" => '2013-03-19'
    ));

} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

This works fine and dandy to create the event, but then afterwards I want to come back and add a Cover Photo to the event using the following code (*again*, found on SO):

```
$cover['cover_url']     = 'MYIMAGE.jpg';
$eventUpdate = $facebook->api( "/" . $fbEvent['id'], 'post', $cover );
```

This code requires an event ID that is generated when the event is posted.. so my question is:
**how do I return the Event ID after posting an event, so it can be used to update my Event Cover Photo?**

Or better yet, **is there a streamlined way of creating the event, and adding the Cover Photo all in one go?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270147/how-do-i-send-this-data-to-facebook-facebook-api-photo-upload?rq=1

Comment: you just want to get event id you created ?

add this code to the end of your first code & you should find helpful informations 
`echo '<pre>';
print_r($retObj);
echo '</pre>';
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just want to get event id you created ?

add this code at the end of your first code
`$id=$retObj['id'];` OR `$id=$retObj[0]['id'];` not sure which one but i think first one should work

you can find helpful information by adding this code at the end of first code
`echo '<pre>';
print_r($retObj);
echo '</pre>';`